# Component declared in nested module doesn't have material styles applied

Tags: angular, angular-material

In the picture you can see a button added with the exact same markup in two spots. The green button is added in my `app.component.html` which is declared in the root `app.module.ts`. That module also is where I import `MatButtonModule` and my nested `TodosModule`.

The red box contains my `todos.component.html` which is declared in my `todos.module.ts`. You can see that button has no material styling applied. Why is that the case? Does my nested module not use the styles imported in my root module?

button html:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary">Add</button>
```

`app.module.ts`

```
import { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material/button";
import { TodosModule } from "./todos/todos.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    TodosModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`todos.module.ts`

```
import { AddToDosComponent } from "./components/add-to-dos/add-to-dos.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AddToDosComponent],
})
export class TodosModule {}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `MatButtonModule` not working as it is only applied to `AppModule` (scope).

Import the `MatButtonModule` in `AppModule` (root module) will **not be inherited** to the child/nested modules.

You should implement a `SharedModule` and **import it into each module** that is required.

> material-theme.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

@NgModule({
  exports: [MatButtonModule],
})
export class MaterialThemeModule {}
```

> shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialThemeModule } from './material-theme.module';

@NgModule({
  exports: [CommonModule, MaterialThemeModule],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

> to-dos.module.ts

```
import { AddToDosComponent } from '../add-to-dos/add-to-dos.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule],
  declarations: [AddToDosComponent],
})
export class TodosModule {}
```

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    SharedModule,
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vcfttu?file=src/app/shared.module.ts)